# How can I use the Zend library, specifically the twitter class with codeigniter?

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, twitter

I'm trying to use the Zend twitter service in codeigniter.

I have used the following method to integrate zend http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/21/using-zend-framework-with-codeigniter/

I can successfully complete the Oauth authentication and receive a valid access token from twitter, and my callback page works fine, but when I try to make a request I get the following error:

```
Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: Client/Result.php

Line Number: 232
```

I'm loading the twitter class like this:

```
$this->load->library('zend');
$this->zend->load('Zend/Service/Twitter');
```

I'm not sure if there's anything else I should be loading, or what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using Codeigniter 2.0.2 and ZendFramework 1.11.4

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a bit more code showing how you are using the Twitter service? I'm assuming simply loading the class isn't what's generating the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error doesn't seem to be related directly with CodeIgniter and Zend. Looking at the code on line 232 I can see this

```
return (string) $result[0];
```

This is within the following function

```
/**
 * toString overload
 *
 * Be sure to only call this when the result is a single value!
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    if (!$this->getStatus()) {
        $message = $this->_sxml->xpath('//message');
        return (string) $message[0];
    } else {
        $result = $this->_sxml->xpath('//response');
        if (sizeof($result) > 1) {
            return (string) "An error occured.";
        } else {
            return (string) $result[0];
        }
    }
}
```

It appears that `$result` is not an array - and to be honest this doesn't seem like a very well thought out function. Try looking into the class in question `Zend/Rest/Client/Result.php`, seeing what `$result` is and if the call to Twitter is actually successful.

Hope that helps.